# How do I associate an earlier username (not OpenID) with my current OpenID login?

Tags: support

I added an answer to a superuser question some time ago using a name entry rather than an OpenID. (Actually, I think the original question was moved from Stack Overflow to superuser.)

Since then, I have discovered the wonders of Stack Exchange and created an OpenID applicable to several areas. How, then, can I associate that original answer and its rep points to my current OpenID username?

Note, I did try to login as that user with the email address I believe I entered, but it sees the email address as new and wants me to create a new account. Is this what I need to do? I want to make sure I'm linking/merging the two correctly. (Just to clarify, I did not create an account when I answered the original question.)

Answer (score 1):

Find a question or answer that was posted under the other account and flag for moderator attention detailing what you want done.

In this case it would be along the lines of:

> Please merge this account back into my current. It was created before I registered and I would like to eat my clone.

Be sure to include any information you can remember to help prove your case. But that's not too dire if you can't. We can double check to make sure things line up.

Once verified, the accounts will be merged and you'll regain ownership of the posts.

Comment: I'll give this a shot! Thanks!